# I don't have "Add" in my database methods

Tags: database, vb.net, entity-framework, methods

As I want to add data to my database, I wanted to use "Add" method but there isn't.
Methods to add to database are only "AddObject" and "AddTo". Even if I choose "AddTo", it suggest to me to use "Add" methods which I don't have it.

This is also same for "remove" method

What is the reason that I don't have "Add" in my method collection?

To add my database to VB.NET I use Entity Model Code Generator which makes a file with the name of "Model1.edmx" in Solution Explorer

Comment: You should start by telling us which classes you're trying to use. A bit hard to guess from our side of things.

Comment: Sounds like Entity Framework.

Comment: Classes are auto generated. I add an entity model code generator to add my database to my program. It makes a file with name of "Model1.edmx"

Comment: Make sure you have DbContext with DbSets. Use code generation item 'DbContext Generator'.

Answer (score 1):

`AddObject` is what your looking for. That method allows you to add records to the tables, and they all follow this pattern.

```
Using db As New model 'or what ever you model is called
 Dim obj As tableName = tableName.CreateTableName({params that are not null})
 db.tableNames.AddObject(obj)
 db.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

Comment: But what if I want to use "Add" method? What can I do for that?And do you mean this problem is because of the way that I connect program to database?

Comment: It just does not exist in this context.

Comment: So with what way i can use add method?

Comment: I don't think your getting the idea behind Entity Framework. Have you gone thru some tutorials?